# Parse Image Comparison

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I need to check if two PFFiles have the same image (pixel for pixel) in them in my cloud code. I went through the parse documentation for "parse-image" and was able to turn the pffiles into two Image objects. However, I don't know how to check if the images are equal. I tried:

```
var foundIt = false;
if (image1 === image2) {
      foundIt = true;
}
// foundIt is false

if (image1.data() === image2.data()) {
     foundIt = true;
}
// foundIt is false (sometimes true, but doesn't match correctly)

if (image1.toString() === image2.toString()) {
      foundIt = true;
}
// foundIt is false (sometimes true, but doesn't match correctly)

if (image1.data().toString() === image2.data().toString()) {
     foundIt = true;
}
// foundIt is false (sometimes true, but doesn't match correctly)
```

So none of these work when I test it with images that I know are identical and images that I know are not identical. I tried checking the documentation, but I wasn't really able to find anything on how to do this.

Comment: The images are the same but created at different times? Created how? Cloud code isn't generally for this you will likely need to add some 3rd party code to help yo

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a Buffer object you could use to do some stuff on cloud code but the documentation for that is also disappeared from Parse. The Parse documentation on Parse-image has very little information but as I looked at it the following code might work:

```
if(image1.data().toString("base64") == image2.data().toString("base64")) {
    foundIt = true;
}
```